# Problema Cifrado Cesar en JAVA

Tags: java, cifrado

Tengo hecho el método de cifrar un String en una clase(he hecho debug y hace bien el cifrado), pero al usar el método en la clase Main no lo codifica y me devuelve el mismo valor. Paso el código para que podáis verlo.

Clase CMachine:

```
public class CMachine {

    public static final int DESPLAZAMIENTO = 5;
    String abc = "abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 ";

    public CMachine() {
        int desplazamiento=DESPLAZAMIENTO;
    }


    public String codificaCesar(String cadena,int desplazamiento) {
        String cadenaCod="";
        for (int i = 0; i < cadena.length() ; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j < abc.length(); j++) {
                if (cadena.charAt(i)==abc.charAt(j)) {
                    cadenaCod+=abc.charAt((j+desplazamiento)%abc.length());
                }
            }
        }
        cadena=cadenaCod;
        return cadena;
    }

}
```

Clase Main:

```
public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        CMachine maquina = new CMachine();

        System.out.println("INTRODUCE UNA FRASE PARA CODIFICAR: ");
        String cadenaOrg = sc.nextLine();


        maquina.codificaCesar(cadenaOrg, 5);
        System.out.println(cadenaOrg);

    }

}
```

Llevo dándole vueltas un rato pero no saco el problema. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que estas imprimiendo el mismo String, que estan ingresando por pantalla, imprime el método completo y se vera el String codificado.

```
public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        CMachine maquina = new CMachine();
        System.out.println("INTRODUCE UNA FRASE PARA CODIFICAR: ");
        String cadenaOrg = sc.nextLine();       
        System.out.println(maquina.codificaCesar(cadenaOrg, 5));

    }
}
```

o puedes imprimir el valor en la clase CMAchine

```
public class CMachine {
    public static final int DESPLAZAMIENTO = 5;
    String abc = "abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 ";

    public CMachine() {
        int desplazamiento=DESPLAZAMIENTO;
    }


    public String codificaCesar(String cadena,int desplazamiento) {
        String cadenaCod="";
        for (int i = 0; i < cadena.length() ; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j < abc.length(); j++) {
                if (cadena.charAt(i)==abc.charAt(j)) {
                    cadenaCod+=abc.charAt((j+desplazamiento)%abc.length());
                }
            }
        }
        cadena=cadenaCod;
        System.out.println("cadena codificada "+cadena);
        return cadena;
    }

}
```

Comment: Efectivamente ese es el problema.

Comment: en realidad, para aclarar, el problema es que no esta haciendo absolutamente nada con el retorno de la funcion

Comment: Madre mia, que estupidez mas grande llevo encima. Muchas gracias. Aveces cuando tienes el cerebro saturado no ves lo mas sencillo.

Answer (score 1):

Exacto, es como dice Patricio. Lo que yo haría en las últimas dos líneas del método main, sería algo así:

```
cadenaCifrada = maquina.codificaCesar(cadenaOrg, 5);
System.out.println(cadenaCifrada);
```

Previamente deberás definir la variable cadenaCifrada, obvio. Y ahí está. Espero que sirva, saludos.